# py2app application is working but Mac OS X shows it as not responding

Tags: python, multithreading, macos, py2app

I have a python script (no GUI) that spawns a child thread, while parent thread is preventing the app from finishing using this method:

```python
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    pass
finally:
    cleanup()
```

When I create an application from this script with py2app and run it, it is staying in Dock and working as expected, but when I right click, it shows that "Application Not Responding" (the same in Activity Monitor) and to finish it I can only select "Force Quit" which results in a crash report dialog afterwards.

Why is it not responding and, if the reason is `sleep()`, how can I keep the app open without it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's showing as "not responding" because it's not responding. An application on OS X (as opposed to just a plain "Unix executable"/script, agent, or daemon) has to respond to messages from the operating system.

Normally, you do this by using a [Cocoa run loop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html). PyObjC offers some [high-level helpers](https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/api/module-PyObjCTools.AppHelper.html) that make it even simpler, or just lets you access the same Cocoa methods that the Apple docs describe from Python.

Another option is to use a script-wrapper that just runs your script while maintaining a run loop (with or without a GUI) for you.

Finally, do you actually need to be an application in the first place?

Comment: so if I am understood well, showing on Deck as not responding doesn't mean it really is not responding ?!

Comment: @Amir No, it really does mean it is not responding. That doesn't mean it's _frozen_; it may well be doing everything it was designed to do--but responding to messages from the OS just isn't part of what it was designed to do.